# Install conda package in pip based Python installation

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda

I have a Python 3.7 installation build with pip and I want to install a package that is only available through conda. Is there a (semi) reliable way to do that? There is a lot of info about the reverse problem but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do that. It's better to create a separate conda environment to your for your project and install there all the packages you need.